# Cannot center an image while placing a text on the bottom left-edge of the image

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I'm having trouble centring the image while placing a text exactly on the bottom left-edge of the image.

```css
.body img {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <img src="" alt="photo" class="image" align="top" />
        <p class = "body_p">
            testing
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `width: fit-content;` style for `img` tag.

```css
.body img {
    margin: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <img src="myself.jpg" alt="photo" class="image" align="top">
        <p class = "body_p">
            testing
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting different size images in `src` and it will centralize. just like background image you can set position an image too. if the image is too big it will show the center area of that image.

```css
img {
  width: 220px;
  height: 165px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/220px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="photo" class="image" align="top">
        <p class = "body_p">
            testing
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```